How to "pasken" that AI translations are good enough to be valid translations
It seems likely that at some point soon, AI will be good at translating hebrew, yiddish, arabic and aramaic into every other language, extremely reliably.
Right now, I imagine that the general "psak"* is that one cannot use AI (or anyone but a human who has proven his worth, minimum) as a targum of Torah (even Rabbinic works), and it would take a specific type of posek, as well as a specific set of conditions, for Klal Yisrael to arrive at a widely accepted "psak"* that one can rely on AI to translate Torah.
Sorry, I can't prove these things (I am not an expert in politics or being a posek) but they seem fairly uncontroversial and straight forward to me, based on experience.
So my question is, what specific conditions, considerations and judgements need to be made in order to, and which specific authority can "pasken"* that we can rely on AI translations?
I think we are one way or another going to run into this issue soon, and it's going to be big, and impactful, so I would be glad to know.
* I put this word in quotes because this question applies on many levels, such as shnayim mikra; a political position such as Artscroll's standards or Sefaria's reliability; or the position of a kehilla or institution, such as the hashkafa of a school. Not levels all including halachic psak in the traditional sense. I want a general answer that covers all bases, ideally, but feel free to cover just one aspect of this question.

As a one-time professional translator, I don't think tranalation methods or even specific human translators are paskened kosher or not....individual books get haskamas or they don't

@יהושעק did you see the point in the asterisk? Perhaps I should highlight it more obviously as part of the conditions of the question?

I had not seen it. I still think it's rough, though....a Torah-specialized AI translator could potentially be endorsed by some body or another, and then the question would be whether any given person holds by that entity, just like anything else (kashrut, siddurim, shofarot), right?

@יהושעק Rough...yes. I guess I am trying to find a specific way to ask a general question - what do we think it will "take" for "klal Yisrael" to "generally" be positive towards relying on AI translations? I don't imagine that happening purely organically, but would require some sort of formal process (or several), and I would like to know what that formal process would theoretically look like

I don't understand the question. No translation source, human or otherwise, is automatically kosher.

@DoubleAA I think there's a confusion between translation and politics. Koshering is a matter of politics, e.g. Unkelos replacing YHWH with YHWH's Kavod. Translation is the matter of understanding the author's mind which even the generation of Tannoyim didn't have.

I would remind you that AI doesn't have a single "translation", it can generate thousands of them given different prompts, e.g "translate the Torah according to Rambam's understanding" or "Ariza"l's understanding", etc. There would be very different depictions of God, angels, the Mishkan, priestly works, etc.

Halachicly speaking, I suggest it falls under the Mishna in Sotah 32: "אלו נאמרין בכל לשון", and technically (not politically, see my comment above) it is as "Kosher" as any other translations.
